# Django - Get sum of field A where field B is equal to either field B or field C, OVER MULTIPLE ROWS?

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
| mac_src           | mac_dst           | bytes_in |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
| aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa | bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb |       10 |
| bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb | aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa |       20 |
| cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc | aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa |       30 |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

I have a table with fields `mac_src`, `mac_dst` and `bytes_in`.

I need to get all rows where each `mac_src` value that exists in the table is present in EITHER `mac_src` or `mac_dst`. I then need the sum of the fields `bytes_in` of all these rows.

I want to get the sum of field `bytes_in` of all rows where the field `mac_src` and `mac_dst` are equal, and then sort this sum from highest to lowest.

The Queryset returned should have just one entry per `mac_src`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple way to do it with just the Django ORM. Just write an SQL query (warning: untested and probably slow SQL below):

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('''
        SELECT mac, SUM(total) FROM (
                      (SELECT mac_src AS mac, SUM(bytes_in) AS total FROM your_table GROUP BY mac_src)
            UNION ALL (SELECT mac_dst AS mac, SUM(bytes_in) AS total FROM your_table WHERE mac_src != mac_dst GROUP BY mac_dst)
        ) AS combined_rows GROUP BY mac
    ''')

    counts = dict(cursor.fetchall())  # {mac1: total_bytes1, ...}
```